# StrictHostKeyChecking config on PSFTP.EXE

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, public-key

I come accross `StrictHostKeyChecking` configuration when I needed to setup `sftp` communication between two servers (e.g. Windows Server ---> Linux Server). As defined [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm) (use find for string match "StrictHostKeyChecking"):

If this flag is set to “yes”, ssh will never automatically add host keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts. If this flag is set to “no”, ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files.

I want to use `PSFTP.EXE` to transfer files to the Unix server from Windows machine and there is obviously no concept of `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. My question is then...what is the equivalent for `StrictHostKeyChecking` for `PSFTP.EXE`. Is it simple `-batch` which avoids interactive prompts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all PuTTY tools (including `psftp`) behave as `StrictHostKeyChecking=ask`.

With `-batch`, `psftp` (and `pscp` and `plink`) behave as `StrictHostKeyChecking=yes`.
If you use this switch and `psftp` finds that server's host key has changed you will get:

> WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH! The server's host key does not
> match the one PuTTY has cached in the registry. This means that either
> the server administrator has changed the host key, or you have
> actually connected to another computer pretending to be the server.
> The new ... key fingerprint is:
> ...
> **Connection abandoned.**

While without the switch (the default behavior), you will get an interactive prompt.

Likewise for the host key of a new server.

---

The `psftp` (nor any other PuTTY tool) **never** behaves as `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. Unless you use some *ugly and insecure* hacks like here: [How to pass echo y to plink.exe for first connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552236/850848).

---

Obviously the `-batch` affects all other prompts too, not just host key prompts (comparing with `StrictHostKeyChecking`). There are these prompts in `psftp` (`pscp` and `plink`):

- Username, passphrase, password, password change and keyboard-interactive prompts (connection aborts with `-batch`)
- Insecure algorithm prompt (the same behavior as with host key prompt)
- Append to existing log file? (logging is disabled with `-batch` when log file already exists and *Ask user every time* option is enabled for *What to do if the log file already exists*)