# plink: unknown option "-rf"

Tags: jenkins, putty, plink

Thanks for looking into my concern.

I am running a command on remote linux server from windows, using plink. Here's the command I am running

```
echo y | plink -v -pw %Linux-pw% -P %port% %Linux-user%@%Linux-Machine% rm -rf /root/jenkins/Sandbox/project1
```

If I execute this command I see the below error in jenkins.

```
11:53:17 plink: unknown option "-rf"
```

Strange thing is I have the same command in two jenkins jobs. One working fine and one job is throwing this issue.

Could anyone suggest something on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this behavior, when the `%port%` variable resolves to an empty string.

Then you get this:

```
echo y | plink -v -pw password -P user@machine rm -rf /root/jenkins/Sandbox/project1
```

What takes `user@machine` as a port number, `rm` as a hostname and `-rf` as an additional switch to Plink.

---

Also, never automate host key verification (`echo y`)!

For the correct solution see [How to pass echo y to plink.exe for first connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552236/850848).

Comment: Brilliant. I missed port variable.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, never automate host key verification (echo y)!

@Martin Prikryl : Can I know the reason for this?

Comment: Host key verification is there to protect your against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). If you automate the verification, you may easily end up sending your username and password to the hacker.