# plink.exe bypass Strict Host Key Checking

Tags: batch-file, ssh, plink

Good day all,

Please can you assist, I am trying to create a for loop to login to routers, load a script and logout all of this via SSH. The problem I am getting is I have 1500 routers I have to login to and I am getting a prompt to allow the fingerprint of the router and allow it.

Is there any way to bypass this Strict Host Key Checking and automatic accept it log in, load the scrip and log out.

I am using the plink.exe client.
My code is below

```
plink.exe -ssh -batch ****@x.x.x.x -pw *** < "%~dp0cmd.txt"
```

Comment: is the prompt a Y/N prompt? Can you show example of this?

Comment: See [How to pass echo y to plink.exe for first connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552236/850848) or [Using echo y as an automated response to a pcp hostkey prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39924091/850848).

Comment: The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 0b:cb:e6:ef:fa:63:ee:ac:5d:6b:a5:28:86:15:9d:0c
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) Using username

Comment: I would like to add that this does not work


`echo y | plink.exe -ssh -batch ****@x.x.x.x -pw *** < "%~dp0cmd.txt`

Comment: @Gerhard it is a Y/N - you can find the example in my first reply

Comment: additionally, if it is more than one `Y/N` prompt, create a text file called `answer.txt` and enter `Y` in it twice, in list form. then try `(plink.exe -ssh -batch ****@x.x.x.x -pw *** < "%~dp0cmd.txt")<answer.txt`

Comment: You cannot combine `|` and `<`. Either one or the other.

Comment: @Gerhard I have tried your method, and it worked to bypass the Fingerprint and accept it automatically. The problem now is the cmd.txt which has the config that needs to be loaded. The good news is I can see that the connection successfully logs in on the router Logs.

Comment: Well I think plink is not able to do what I want to do. Because it is not doing the command and it takes to long to log in. Think Linux is the best way out

Comment: So did you try adding the `Y` to your `cmd.txt`?!? (not that I endorse this at all)

Comment: @StefanMostert, ok, so that means it accepts the input, so try adding `Y` to the top line of the `cmd.txt` file and run the original `plink.exe -ssh -batch ****@x.x.x.x -pw *** < "%~dp0cmd.txt"`